# Modal Resize in Ionic framework 6

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, modal-dialog

I am using Ionic frame work 6 and Angular 13 for my application. I want to resize the ionic modal in this. I tried to pass a global class along with the creation. It is not working. I tried to resize the wrapper class. Its working in the previous version of Ionic -5. But not here. Please help. Thanks in advance.

commonService.ts

````
async createPopup(options) {
    options.componentProps.service = this;
    const ref = await this.modalController.create({
      component: AppModalPopupComponent,
      ...options
    });
    if (!this.modalPopup?.length) { this.modalPopup = []; }
    this.modalPopup.push(ref);
    ref.present();

    return ref;
  }


component.ts


this.modalService.createPopup(
      {
        backdropDismiss: true,
        componentProps: {
          header: 'Update Banner in My Queue',
          component: AppUpdateImagePopoverComponent
        },
        cssClass: "image-popup-modal-css"
      });```

Global.scss

.image-popup-modal-css {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: var(--app-secondary-color);
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.image-popup-modal-css .modal-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(min-content, max-content);
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top:0
}
````

Comment: Please share your code Or output

Comment: @RaviAshara, pls have a look at now. I could not control the height even with wrapper class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In ionic 5 I was using this:

```css
.example-modal {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; 
  .modal-wrapper { 
    --height: 80%; 
    --width: 50%;   
  }
}
```

And in Ionic 6 I changed to this

```css
.example-modal {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; 
  &::part(content){
    width: 80%;
    height: 50%; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @nicolas acerenza. It worked for me

Comment: It is working fine in latest ios versions, but the older device it still having same issue

Comment: How to set auto height? `height: auto;` doesn't appear to work.

Comment: @PitchaimuthuKanakaraj The documentation is here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal#css-shadow-parts you might need to style the other parts later on.

Answer (score 1):

work's fine in all versions

```
.example-modal {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  --min-height: 80%; 
  --min-width: 50%;
  --max-height: 80%; 
  --max-width: 50%;
}
```